# Which method is the most appropriate for removing object keys which might be accessed after removal?

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

My dilema is as follows: I have been using the delete method for removing object keys, keys which some functions try to access after removal and I discovered that this has been causing a small, tiny... huge memory leak over time.

I have been trying to find a good answer for this, but so far no luck. The only light reference I found explained that it is best to turn the object key into null instead of using delete to avoid memory leaks.

Now I have been wondering about which method will be the best for the case that I described (and perhaps as an overall best practice):

1 - delete Object.key

2 - Object.key = null

3 - Object.key = ""

4 - Object.key = void(0)

5 - Object.key = function(){}

6 - Another method(s) that I didn't list - provide the method as example

So far number 1 seems to be pretty much out of the question for this case where functions try to access the deleted keys, does anyone else have any knowledge that could advise me on this?

If possible please provide comparison(s) or an explanation showing the advantage(s) of the method(s) that you know to be the best for this scenario.

PS: The object keys that need to be removed can be anything; a function, boolean, string, etc.

Comment: Since you seem to have a testable environment ready to go, what are your observations? BTW, `void 0` is one character less to type. ;-)

Comment: I don't really have an answer for you, but I definitely wouldn't recommend `function(){}` because it is truthy.

Comment: `delete obj.key` does not cause a memory leak in any way.  If some other code is leaking because a key doesn't exist, then you need to go fix that code, not fix the key.  If the key doesn't need to exist, then the best practice is to remove it with `delete`.

Comment: @RobG I had before I went on a travel. Just checked something another user helped me with and now I don't have the possibility to conduct the experiments myself, so I wondered "why not ask the community? someone might know this already". Clint Powell I see the predicament as well as when some function tries to check if the key is null, or empty, etc, but surely there must be a decent alternative for delete, I hope.

Comment: @jfriend00 The problem is that this is a userscript environment so I do not have access to the original page script that is causing the memory leak (it does so because I am trying to make it work in a way that it shouldn't, like most userscripts), it kept stacking whenever it tried to access the removed keys it needed and after a while the memory usage was almost 1GB (not a short while, but still). This was reduced when I started using the `null` method, however I am still noticing a little pile up going on somewhere - inexistent if I don't delete keys.

Comment: @Shadow - then there is NO generic best practice. Use whatever causes the least harm with the mal-behaving external script.  You can only figure that out by studying or testing the mal-behaving script with different options.  If the usual value of the key was a string, then an empty string would be a logical guess, but you really just have to test.  If the usual value was an object, then either an empty object or `null` would be logical guesses depending upon how the bad code works.

Comment: @jfriend00 Seriously? Well, that's too bad. In that case the best option, I suppose, is to individually change each key in a way that won't cause conflict with the functions that are trying to use it and reach my goals as well. The work will be too exaustive so I think the best less-time-consuming-effective option is the one you told me. Edit: just read your added text after I submitted mine, you read my mind.

Comment: @jfriend00 Just wanted to leave an update now that I was able to conduct the experiment myself and it is as we both concluded: the best option is to do it individually, but since in my case I have to get rid of close to 100 keys I went with the empty string method, which works best in my case and happened to be better than null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with mal-behaving code that you can't change, there is no best practice for what to do with these keys.  All you can do is study or test the code and try to figure out which value for the key causes the least harm.

This isn't a language thing.  It isn't a best practice thing.  There is no magic answer that will always be the best answer.  You're trying to work-around bad code by finding a value that causes the least harm and the only way to know that answer is by figuring out what value works best with that particular bad code.

If the usual value of the key was a string, then an empty string would be a logical guess, but you really just have to test. If the usual value was an object, then either an empty object or null would be logical guesses depending upon how the bad code works.  If the usual value is a function, then perhaps you could try an empty function as a guess.

To summarize.  Study, guess, test and pick the option that gives you the best results (or least bad results).

Comment: I have selected yours as the answer as per our mutual agreement during the comments, thank you all for taking your time with this.